# GTM: Cannot track click on menu elements

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to capture all click events on the menu of my page.

I've setup a tag that will capture all click events on my page. It works with the trigger setup to "Click - All elements".

When I set up the trigger to specifically register only the clicks on elements of the menu var, nothing is detected. So, definetly, I'm doing somenthing wrong within the trigger.

**EDIT 1:**

this is the web page: www.chazki.com

Menu code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active">
                <a class="new_service">Solicita un Chazki</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="/faq">Faq</a>
              </li>
              <li>
               <p  class="new_service new-service" style=" padding: 6px;"><a>Login</a></p>                
              </li>
              <li>
                <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg location_ac"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-spin fa-star"></i>Lima</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form>
            <fieldset class="navbar-form navbar-left">
    <input type="text" name="track-code" id="track-code" class="form-control" placeholder="Código de tracking?">
    <button id="track-find-button" class="btn btn-default" type="button">Buscar</button>
   </fieldset>
            </form>

          </div>
```

Try 1 on trigger:

Element ID: It's supposed to limit the clicks registered for only the div containing the menu.

[image]

I get this error in debugging mode:

[image]

Try 2 on trigger:

on Click ID.

[image]

Click ID error:

[image]

#

I could also use the ul tag for the trigger, as it is the only unordered list on the page.

Any hint is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the ability to change the source code of your website?

Comment: It's not working becuase element which is returned in click ID or element ID is NOT the whole section <div ... id="navbar-ex-collapse"> but rather just one specific element inside. In your case it's either going to be <a> or <li> element.

Comment: @Matus I've tried using Click ID contains li does not work, same for a tag. Any other hint? Thanks!

Comment: @faridghar I could ask to insert some ids, but the idea is not to botter so much IT. Is not possible without bothering IT?

Comment: I don't have time to give a full answer right now but read this: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/capturing-the-correct-element-in-google-tag-manager/
This is your problem, as @Matus said. I will post a full solution later today if I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I needed to understand the different variables in GTM. I've found Simo Ahava web very helpful in this regard.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/variable-guide-google-tag-manager/

[image]

Thanks to Simo, I also understood the benefits of usen "Match CSS Selector" option.

So my configuration ended like this:

[image]

Using:

1. Click All Elements.
2. This trigger fires on "Some Clicks".
3. "Click Element" -> "Matches CSS Selector" -> "#navbar-ex-collapse ul li a, #navbar-ex-collapse ul li p"

As I have `li` and `a` html elements, I needed to use 2 CSS selectors, separated by a comma.